# How may I may fit the cluster number while it is going to the outside of the X-axis and when visualizing clusters in two dimensions?

Tags: python, clustering, matplotlib, seaborn, dbscan

I am writing code for `DBSCAN` clustering. I find the `eps` value which is `0.12` with the help of the `Elbow/Knee method`. But in the plot, the `cluster number` is going to the out of the `X-axis`. It about `177 clusters` and only `13 clusters` fitted within the figure box. But the other `164 clusters` generated the outer side of the `X-axis`. So how may I fix this problem?

My code:

```
import seaborn as sns
dbscan = DBSCAN(eps=distances[knee.knee], min_samples=10).fit(Y)
labels = dbscan.labels_

#fig = plt.figure(figsize=(5, 5))
#fig = plt.figure(figsize=(36,12))

sns.scatterplot(Y[:,0], Y[:,1], hue= ["cluster-{}".format(x) for x in labels])


plt.title("DBSCAN Clustering Method")
plt.xlabel('Number of clusters', fontsize = 10) 
plt.ylabel('Silhouette Score', fontsize = 10) 
plt.title('DBSCAN Cluster with Silhouette Score Method ')

plt.show()
```

[image: DBSCAN Cluster]

Comment: @dan-scally Dear mentor please help me to fix this problem.

Comment: @65767 Dear mentor please help me to fix this problem